# Stokes theorem with divergent form

Tags: differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

Let $M$ be a manifold and $S$ a smooth imbedded hypersurface $S \subset M$ that divides $M$ into two disjoint connected components: $M \setminus S \simeq M^1 \cup M^2$.

Is Stokes theorem, stated as

$\int_M d\omega =\int_{\partial M} \omega$ ,

still valid if $\omega$ takes an infinite value at $S$? We assume that $S$ does not intersect with the boundary of $M$, i.e. $S \cap \partial M = \oslash$?

Comment: If $\omega$ is unbounded, it is not even clear why the expression is well defined.

Comment: Stokes's Theorem makes sense (in fact, is partly definition) for currents, which are differential forms with locally integrable coefficients. ... Also, see the discussion of Stokes's Theorem with singularities in Lang's *Analysis*.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have edited the question to explain myself better, I was being very imprecise. $\omega$ is bounded in $\partial M$ so the right hand side is well-defined. Also at the left hand side one might think about writing it as $\int_M d\omega = \int_M_1 d\omega + \int_M_2 d\omega$ and therefore the left hand side would be well-defined as well. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course you know this, but I thought it worth pointing out that currents are more violent than just passing to locally integrable coefficients! They're forms with distributional coefficients, so you can have a measure as a coefficient of a volume form, say, or something more complicated yet.

Comment: @PeteWanchope There's no reason to believe that those integrals exist unless you make assumptions about integrability. Take $M = [-1,1]$, $S = \{0\}$, and $\omega = dx/x$.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks. Would it be a sufficient condition if $\lim_{\vec{x_{1}}\rightarrow S}\omega=\lim_{\vec{x_{2}}\rightarrow S}\omega$ being $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ coordinates in $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ respectively?